# Rounding position with mouse constant update FIXED

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mouseevent, rounding, updating

I'm making a mario maker style game in C# (unity) where everything has to snap to a grid. I want to, while I'm dragging it, have the item snap into place closest to each int.

```
 void FixedUpdate () {
      Vector2 pos = Input.mousePosition;
      pos.x = Mathf.Round(pos.x);
      pos.y = Mathf.Round(pos.y);
      pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (pos);
      transform.position = pos;
 }
```

This does not work for me, and I've been trying for hours to fix this. Nothing has helped so far, I've gone through every forum I could find to no avail. Please help!!

Comment: Hey there, if you've solved the problem, don't edit your question post to include the answer. Instead, create an answer post below that details what the issue turned out to be and how you solved it.

Comment: @Serlite Sorry about that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should round values after changing pixel pos to world pos.
I mean, after 
    pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (pos);

Let me know result.
If it not work, I would think another try.

Comment: Aha! I just figured it out as you submitted it! Thanks for the reply, and it most definitely worked. Needed some sleep to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

update the rounded positions AFTER you do the mouse position changes.

```
void FixedUpdate () {
     Vector2 pos = Input.mousePosition;
     pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (pos);
     pos.x = Mathf.Round(pos.x);
     pos.y = Mathf.Round(pos.y);
     transform.position = pos;
}
```